# Could not find custom method in androidx.appcompat.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler in MaterialButton

Tags: android

I have recently ported my app to material design and I have started to receive weird errors suggesting that methods are not found in activity (while they are and where there for last 3 years or so) and everything ends in crash for user. This seems to happen only to users that are running Android 4.* (4.0.2, 4.2, 4.4), various devices (Samsung and LG), any suggestions how to address it are appreciated! :)

Full error message:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Could not find a
>   method *onCancelClicked*(View) in the activity class
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on
>   view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id
>   '*btnCancel*'
>
> (...)
>
> Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException onCancelClicked [class
>   android.view.View]

parts in italic are custom methods, see below for the layout

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onCancelClicked"
        android:text="@string/dialog_conf_code_cancel" />
```

Activity handling this layout implements `AppCompatActivity`, while the `onCancelClicked` is simple, as below:

```
public void onCancelClicked(View v) {
    this.finish();
}
```

I also get similar errors for other buttons implemented in this way, again - so far only for *some* users with Android 4.*.

My dependencies in `build.gradle` are defined as below

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.2.0'
}
```

Again - any suggestions are appreciated! :)

Comment: The latest support library is [28.0.0 not 28.2.0](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html). Anything newer is released as [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn). `com.google.android.material` requires AndroidX yet you depend on the old support library. Did you enable [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate)? Remove `com.android.support:design`, it's an older version of `com.google.android.material:material`, you would get errors.

Comment: Yes, Jetifier is enabled. I've updated dependencies and pushed the release, let's see if the problems will be gone. Interesting enough is that when I test it locally everything seems to be fine.

Comment: This solution worked for me perfectly:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311934/7398620

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking with several seemingly related links, the best course of action is to remove all `android:onClick` from XML layouts and attach the click listeners in Java instead.

My feeling about this is that it's not clear what combinations of Android and AndroidX cause this. So setting the listener in Java seems the best solution as it avoids the issue completely.

See also:

- https://code.briarproject.org/briar/briar/issues/334
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37048075
- [Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class TintContextWrapper for onClick if using themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383140/could-not-find-a-method-onclickview-in-the-activity-class-tintcontextwrapper-f)

Comment: Ok, let me try this approach, thank you for the suggestion! :). Fixing dependencies didnt help unfortunately ;-)