# Thrown NoSuchMethodException on click view

Tags: android, proguard

I have an app published in the play store with proguard rules enable and I am receiving some error reports from Android versions 4.4 and 4.2 with this trace error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
      at android.view.View$1.onClick (View.java:3949)
      at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4633)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:19270)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5602)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
      at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod (Class.java:472)
      at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:857)
      at android.view.View$1.onClick (View.java:3942)
      at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4633)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:19270)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:733)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5602)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

As there is no reference to the `method` that is been called or the `Activity` and I am not able to reproduce it, I have no idea how could I fix it. (Most of the project is in java although some classes are in kotlin)

In the proguard file I have excluded domain models and some retrofit clasess, like:

```
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.example.mypackage.DataModel.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.mypackage.WS.** { *; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While updating the project (gradle version, appCompat -> androidX ...) I was forced to correct some lint uses, and one of them was to change a custom TextView that extended TextView to AppCompatTextView.

I had forgotten that in old Android versions when you extend a custom view from AppCompatView all your xml onClick properties no longer work, and NoSuchMethodException is thrown.

You can find some references here:

[Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class TintContextWrapper for onClick if using themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383140/could-not-find-a-method-onclickview-in-the-activity-class-tintcontextwrapper-f)

[Could not find custom method in androidx.appcompat.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler in MaterialButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028752/could-not-find-custom-method-in-androidx-appcompat-widget-tintcontextwrapper-for)